# Calling objects of other class in php?

Tags: php

I am working on a website with php/mysql.

I have 3 files `config.php`, `utils.php` and `member.php`. code of the files are as below,

config.php - `$objPath->docrootlibs` is fine, I am sure there is no problem with this.

```
    /* Other library files & their object */
    require($objPath->docrootlibs.'/utils.php');
    $objUtils = new utils();

    require($objPath->docrootlibs.'/member.php');
    $objMember = new member();
```

utils.php

```
    class utils{
        function getCurrentDateTimeForMySQL(){
            return date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        }
    }
```

members.php

```
    class member{
        var $userid;
        var $username;

        function __construct(){
            $this->lastactivity = $objUtils->getCurrentDateTimeForMySQL();
        }
    }
```

Now when I am including the `config.php` inside a page `home.php` with simple php include statement and running that page then it gives me following error.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: objUtils in D:\wamp\www\site\libs\member.php on line 17

Fatal error: Call to a member function getCurrentDateTimeForMySQL() on a non-object in D:\wamp\www\site\libs\member.php on line 17
```

Line numbers in error above are different, I just copied the specific part from the code here.

I am not understanding why its giving error, because objects of utils class is defined on config page before including the member class. It should detect that object.

Please check and help me to understand and correct this error.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you need to make use of EXTEND?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### One Solution

Unlike JavaScript PHP will not bubble up through scopes, which means

```
    public function __construct(){
        $this->lastactivity = $objUtils->getCurrentDateTimeForMySQL();
    }
```

does not know what `$objUtils` is, because there is no such object defined in the local scope. This means, you have to make the object available inside that scope. The cleanest and most maintainable way to do that is to inject the utils instance to the member instance, e.g.

```
    public function __construct($utils){
        $this->lastactivity = $utils->getCurrentDateTimeForMySQL();
    }
```

However, since you seem to be using that value on construction only anyway, there is no reason why your member instance has to know how to use the utils object. So why not just insert the actual value right from the start, e.g.

```
    public function __construct($lastActivity){
        $this->lastactivity = $lastActivity;
    }

    // then do
    $utils  = new utils();
    $member = new member($utils->getCurrentDateTimeForMySQL());
```

---

#### On globals

You definitely do **not** want to use the `global` keyword or `static` methods. Both couple back to the global scope. This means you can no longer use the member class without the global scope. This makes maintaining, reusing, refactoring and testing harder. OOP is about encapsulation and by reaching out from the class to the global scope you are breaking that encapsulation. Use Dependency Injection as shown above instead.

Apart from that, using globals will also make your code harder to read. A developer looking at the ctor signature of member is likely to assume there is nothing else to do than just call `new member`. That's a lie, because she also has to setup the utils instance. In other words, you are hiding dependencies. The developer has to look at the actual code to understand what's going on. Thus, make dependencies explicit.

Some more resources:

- http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad
- http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-brittle-global-state-singletons/

---

#### EDITs after comments

If you *really* need that utils object, inject the instance and assign it to a property inside the member instance in the ctor. Then you can access it with `$this->utils->foo()` from anywhere else inside the member instance.

However, Utility classes are almost always a sign of bad design. It is much more likely that they should be broken apart and divided into/onto other objects. Try to find out the reponsibilities. Maybe Member should not use Utils, but Utils should be something else that uses Members.

Out of curiosity, why do you need a utility method for MySql anyway? If you use a Timestamp column in MySql for lastActivity, it will automatically update whenever the row is updated. I am assuming you are setting the lastActivity and then store the member data?

Regarding performance: you should not bother about performance. Write readable and maintainable code first and foremost. If you think your performance is not good enough, profile the application with XDebug to see what is really making an impact.

Comment: @Gordon, I used constructor method just to demonstrate the problem. Actually constructor is not the single method where I need to access functions of Utils class. Inside member class there are other functions as well, who needs to access functions of utils class. So I need a oops based logical and optimized way to resolve this issue. If I'll include too much files and create objects inside each file then it maybe the performance issue I suppose?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, my internet was down. Ok, so if one need to write the above code (my code in question) as readable code then what's the way, what's your suggestions? I found one other dirty way as well, though I am not sure its correct method to go with or not, what I did is, defined a var below `var $username;` as `var $objUtils;` and then inside _construct defined it as `$this-objUtils = new Utils();`. This allowed me to access any function of utils class like `$this->objUtils->UtilsFunction();`

Comment: Yes I can define the timestamp but its just an example, I have other functions to call. I am taking all my common functions which can be used by Member and other pages/classes in Utils class? Is it wrong? or I should go in some other way? Please suggest!

Comment: @Prashant you should not use `var` for properties anymore but a visibility keyword, for instance `protected`. Apart from that, yes, that's what I meant with "assign it to a property." - there isn't anything else I can suggest without seeing any concrete code. Consider making it a new question.

Comment: @Gordon, I am not understanding "concrete code", what you want to see. Actually this is what my situation is, I have utils, members classes made in different files with thier specific functions and code. I am including all those inside a config and then further including that config inside all my php pages to have access of these functions and classes. If you can suggest me something in this, would be great. I'm not using any framework, its manual coded app. Thanks for all your help, it will be great if you can help me understanding how we go with oops usually in php? What's the right way.

Comment: @Prashant can you come to the chat please.

Answer (score 2):

As another comment states, use dependency injection.  Insert the utilities object into the constructor.  Do not introduce variables over the global scope, especially between different files.  This gets very confusing and creates a mandatory order of some file includes.

```
class member {
   ...
   public function __construct(utils $objUtils) {
      $this->objUtils = $objUtils;
      ...
   }
}
```

In calling code:

```
$member = new member(new utils);
```

As an aside, I find it humorous that you have a macro with a name that is longer than the operation it performs.

As another aside, do you need a utilities class?  Can the utilities just be functions?

Comment: I have created `objMembers` and `objUtils` inside the config, because I need to call functions in side those class on almost all the pages. So did this and as config.php is included in all the files, so no better area to define such variables. If I'll not define them inside config then I must need to declare them inside all pages? And about which Macro you are talking, not aware?

Comment: I meant macro in the generic sense: getCurrentDateTimeForMySQL() is longer to type than what it does.  If you do not create the object variables in config.php then yes, you would have to create the variables on each page where they are used.

Comment: I didn't say there was anything wrong with it, it's just humorous.  If you have autocompletion, there isn't much lost in terms of time typing it out.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like config.php is in the global scope. You need to use the [global](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) keyword when using $objUtils

```
    function __construct(){
        global $objUtils;
        $this->lastactivity = $objUtils->getCurrentDateTimeForMySQL();
    }
```

Comment: I would rather suggest passing it into the constructor.

Comment: -1 for using the `global` keyword. OOP is about encapsulation. Use Dependency Injection instead.

Comment: Yeah I should have thought of that when I answered. Still I'll leave this up so others can see the stigma against the global keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Since your getCurrentDateForMySQL doesn't depend on anything else inside your utils object, why not make it a static function? That way you can turn your member() method into:

```
function __construct(){
    $this->lastactivity = utils::getCurrentDateTimeForMySQL();
}
```

Comment: True. but it's no less dirty than dependency injection.

Comment: dependency injection is dirty?!?